# jQuery tablesorter.js error line 600

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I want to use [tablesorter.js](http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html).

In FireBug when I launch `$("#myTable").tablesorter();`, it returns `[table#myTable.table]`.

But when I want to sort with `$("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} );`, it returns this error :

```
TypeError: table.config.parsers is undefined
...tion("text", "asc", c) : makeSortFunction("text", "desc", c)) : ((order == 0) ? ...
jquery.tablesorter.js (ligne 600)
```

There's no error at page launching and I use `ready` function to lauch tablesorter.

Here a short version :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() { 
   $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
});
</script>

<table id="myTable" class="table table-condensed table-striped tablesorter">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>Nom</th>
   <th>Taille</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

I use bootstrap from twitter.

Comment: Can we see the html for the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of re-initializing the plugin to change the sort on a table, a `sorton` event should be triggered on the table. See [this demo](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-trigger-sort.html), and try this code:

```
var sorting = [[0,0], [1,0]];

// note: the square brackets around sorting are required!
$("table").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
```

I also made [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/193/) to show that using the `sortList` option should work.

But I wonder if you're only having this issue in IE? I seem to remember IE not liking camel-cased ID's... maybe try changing the table id to `mytable` instead of `myTable`.

Comment: Odd, I'm not seeing any error. Maybe try my [forked version of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/)?

Comment: @Mottie - I've had this same problem (reproduced in Chrome 23). Your forked version seems to have resolved it, so thanks for the suggestion. (...sorting still isn't working properly, but if I can't work that out I'll post it as a separate question)

Comment: @Mottie - have managed to reproduce the same error in your forked version, although not as easily. Line 719: c.parsers is undefined. This happens when you create a table without specifying any sort parameters with zero rows to start, and then dynamically add your rows after defining it as a tablesorter table. I guess without any initial rows, the tablesorter doesn't populate the parsers, even with defaults. I'll do a bit more digging and file a bug ticket.

Comment: @Spudley Thanks! I'll get working on this after the holiday :)

Comment: @Spudley The issue you described should now be fixed!

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same error. After digging through the plugin code and messing around I discovered that the number of header cells do not match the number of columns. It was a bad HTML after all, not the script. tablesorter works perfectly since then.

Comment: For the future, stuff like "I've got the same error" is unnecessary and even detrimental to your answer.  Try to only include the solution and _relevant_ configuration information.

Comment: I thought so too, but it seems like they're suggesting the OP check that the number of columns in the `thead` match the number in the `tbody`.